# Why dynamic objects inside ScrollView won't scroll with the other content?

Tags: qt, qml

So in my QML application I a have got a ScrollView with some fixed content.
Then I'd like to add some dynamic content (with Javascript) inside this ScrollView.

The problem is that this newly created objects won't scroll up and down with the other content (the Image).

What am I doing wrong?

**CODE:**

```
import QtQuick 2.15

import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2


Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480


    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    signal hideBounds(bool hide)

    property var newArrow: []

    color: "light grey"


    function destroyArrow(number) {

        newArrow[number].destroy(500)


    }

    ScrollView {

        id: scroll

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        contentHeight: pdfImage.height

        Image {
            id: pdfImage

            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

            width:parent.width*0.8

            x: (parent.width-width)/2

            source: "file:///Users/Riccardo/Downloads/file.png"



        }

        Component.onCompleted: {

            var component = Qt.createComponent("CompleteArrow.qml")

            for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                newArrow[i] = component.createObject(scroll, {id: "dynamicArrow"+i, arrayNumber: i, quoteNumber: (i + 1), x: scroll.width*0.05, y: i, width: scroll.width*0.1, height: scroll.width*0.1, mirror: true, flip:false})

                newArrow[i].destroyMe.connect(destroyArrow)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentItem-prop):

> Items created dynamically need to be explicitly parented to the contentItem.

So your call to `createObject` needs to change to this:

```
newArrow[i] = component.createObject(scroll.contentItem, ...)
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, the link to the docs I gave was for `Flickable`. For some reason, I was thinking a ScrollView was a Flickable, but it's not. I still think the answer might work, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though it does not work, I've just tried it right now.